# nginx responding to telnet but not to wget/browser

Tags: nginx, wget

My personal site is hosted by nginx.

I tried wget and got this:

[image]

I tried telnet with the same http header and telnet is ok:
[image]

Browsers behave the same with wget.

this confused me for several days.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I got the cause.

My domain name is not put on records at government.

this case has little value to others. Ignore it.